# Micro CloudFoundry not available anymore?

Tags: cloud-foundry

Does anyone knows if the "micro" version of CloudFoundry will be still available?

The https://micro.cloudfoundry.com site does not respond but I've got a link to it in my pivotal account so naturally I assume something must have gone wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Micro Cloud Foundry has not been upgraded for Cloud Foundry v2. The following links gives the two alternative options:

http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/docs/running/deploying-cf/run-local.html

I can recommend [cf-vagrant-installer](https://github.com/Altoros/cf-vagrant-installer) which enables you to run CF on virtualbox, using vagrant. This is a more flexible approach compared to the older micro CF, which required VMWare.

Comment: seems link is dead, will you please update the same?

Comment: @sakura Yes correct the link is dead. So is Micro Cloud Foundry. I suggest looking at Micro Bosh: http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/deploying/openstack/deploying_microbosh.html

Comment: @MarkO'Connor Thank you, I am struggling to deploy CF on windows machine.. No step by step guide. I think Micro Bosh steps are again applicable for windows. let me know if you have some reference for cf setup on windows.

Answer (score 2):

Update: the vagrant option is now called "Bosh-lite" and is available under: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh-lite

Supported Virtualizations are:
* VMWAre Fusion
* VirtualBox
* AWS

Answer (score 1):

MicroPCF will be replaced by pcfdev (currently version 0.15) but it's still in beta. All you have to do is a vagrant up. It will have MySQL, Redis and Rabbit as Service out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

"Micro Cloud Foundry is not yet available for the Cloud Foundry Hosted Developer Edition (v2). If you are a Cloud Foundry v1 customer, please use Offline Mode." - from the Google cached result for micro.cloudfoundry.com

This blog post has instructions for working in offline mode: http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2011/09/08/working-offline-with-micro-cloud-foundry/

Answer (score 0):

The "Micro" version of Cloud Foundry is not available for Cloud Foundry V2 users onward. 
Check those options to run Cloud Foundry V2 locally:
http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/deploying/run-local.html

This currently includes bosh-lite and cf_nise_installer.